# Subtracting Dates, Returning result in Months

Tags: javascript

I have two dates on a form I have built, both requiring entry in MM/DD/YYYY format. What is the best way to return the number of months that has passed between those dates?

I am writing this in a dependency so my variables will be named by: #MyVar (e.g. #Date1 and #Date2).

Thanks,
pm

Comment: Try by yourself and when you have a specific problem come here and ask for that specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) makes problems like this trivial.

If you can't afford to include a dependency, you'd have to just work it out in JS. Store the number of days in each month, write a little function that deals with leap years, and then do the arithmetic.

Comment: I won't be able to use Moment.js this time around, but will definitely use it on the next form. Thanks!